# After concat() in Pandas, the new DF is missing "00"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I ran into this problem:

After webscraping (bs4) i have now two Excel-Files: All works fine.
When I concat() or even just append with pandas, i get the "Major-Excel". Unfortunately, in the Column "EAN" many rows show a missing "0" or even "00" in the beginning. 
For Example:

```
Product 1: 36073...
Product 2:   883...
Product 3:  7370...
```

It should be like this:

```
Product 1: 36073...
Product 2: 00883...
Product 3: 07370...
```

This problem only happens when the ean starts with "0" or "00".
Besides i also checked the single Excel Files that i want to concat(): The "0" are also there so this problem only happens when i want to put the two into 1 file.

I am actually just using this standard script:

```py
d = pd.read_excel('one.xlsx')
d1 = pd.read_excel('two.xlsx')

three = pd.concat([d, d1])
three.to_excel('major.xlsx')
```

Anybody experienced the same problem?

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the column type is default to integer and dropping the leading 0's. Declare the column as a varchar before the concatenation?

```
d = pd.read_excel('one.xlsx', converters={'EAN':str})
```

Comment: Many Thanks! Really appreciate your instruction!